# Adjust footer in MS Word to compensate for portrait/landscape orientation

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, headers, footers

I have used section breaks to make some pages in my document portrait and others landscape.  This works great, but the only problem is that the footer (and header for that matter) are setup for portrait pages, so on the landscape pages, it doesn't look right.  Is there a way to compensate so that the footer is different on landscape pages and portrait pages? (see image below)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an **Alignment Tab** which is a special type of tab that works relative to the page margin. Simply replace your ordinary tabs with one center tab and one right aligned tab of this type and after you have done this you will find the text aligns itself properly to the page margins for both page orientations.

[image]
[image]

**The result:**

[image]